# Is there an efficient systematic way to find relations between powers of Matrices?

Tags: matrix-exponential

Hi I have a 3 by 3 matrix of the following form:
$$ 
A=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & 0 \\
-b & a & c \\
0 & -c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$a,b,c,d\in\Re $$
I'm trying to explore special relations between powers of this matrix of the form:
$$
A^n = \alpha A^m
$$
or even for the simpler case where $$a=d=0$$
The motivation is to use one of the closed form special cases for the matrix exponential, I didn't find anything so far from exploring the literature, and I wonder if there is a systematic efficient way to go about it?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to focus on one question, otherwise it might get closed. The "simpler case" is much simpler. Also, are the coefficients real or complex?

Comment: thanks, updated it

Comment: you can form its characteristic polynomial and then you can easily form a recurrence relation for the powers of the matrix

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't understand fully what characteristic polynomial are you referring to and how to use it further? I'll be happy if you can elaborate

Answer (score 2):

This answer is restricted to the case $a=d=0$. Then one can check that $$A^3=(b^2+c^2)A$$ So writing $\beta:=\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$, then \begin{align}
e^A&=I+A+\frac{A^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{A^n}{n!}+\cdots\\
&=I+\left(1+\frac{\beta^2}{3!}+\frac{\beta^4}{5!}+\cdots\right)A+\left(\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{\beta^2}{4!}+\cdots\right)A^2\\
&=I+\frac{\sinh\beta}{\beta}A + \frac{\cosh\beta-1}{\beta^2}A^2\\
&=I+uA+vA^2\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}1-vb^2&ub&vbc\\-ub&1-\beta^2v&uc\\vbc&-uc&1-vc^2\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you!